# ovs-ofctl doen not work - connection refused

Tags: sockets, mininet, openflow, openvswitch

I am following openflow tutorial on [openflow tutorial](https://github.com/mininet/openflow-tutorial/wiki/Learn-Development-Tools). I am using mininet and ryu controller and openvswitch version 2.8.0. When I try to use command:

> sudo ovs-ofctl show s1

It gives error as below:

> asd@asd:~/ryu/ryu/mpls$ sudo ovs-ofctl show s1
>
> ovs-ofctl: /var/run/openvswitch/s1.mgmt: failed to open socket (Connection refused)

As I am using **sudo**, I think there should not be any problem regarding permissions for opening socket connection. Not sure what is causing this error.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: This error usually means that Open vSwitch is not running. Can you check you have a `ovs-vswitchd` process running?

Comment: Yeah got it. It was problem with openvswitch installation

Comment: Good! I made my comment into an answer for anyone looking into this issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is saying that `ovs-vswitchd` did not open the Unix socket expected at `/var/run/openvswitch/s1.mgmt`. **This usually means that `ovs-vswitchd` (the daemon process for Open vSwitch) is not running**.

You can check that by running:

```
$ ps aux | grep ovs-vswitchd
root      77289  0.0  0.0  25632  4916 ?        Ss   16:05   0:00 ovsdb-server --remote=punix:/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock --remote=db:Open_vSwitch,Open_vSwitch,manager_options --private-key=db:Open_vSwitch,SSL,private_key --certificate=db:Open_vSwitch,SSL,certificate --bootstrap-ca-cert=db:Open_vSwitch,SSL,ca_cert --log-file=/var/log/openvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.log -vsyslog:info -vfile:info --pidfile --detach
root      77295  100  0.2 2608140 45820 ?       Ssl  16:05   3:13 ovs-vswitchd unix:/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock --pidfile --detach --log-file=/var/log/openvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.log -vfile:info
paul      77447  0.0  0.0  14228   968 pts/2    S+   16:08   0:00 grep --color=auto ovs-vswitchd
```

The first process, `ovsdb-server`, answers to OVSDB queries. The second process, `ovs-vswitchd`, answers to OpenFlow queries and processes packets.